# JetBrains Rider - The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: msbuild, mono, rider

I am trying to build a former Windows project in JetBrains Rider on a Mac. I am getting the following build error:

> NuGet.targets(100, 9): [MSB4175] The task factory "CodeTaskFactory"
>   could not be loaded from the assembly
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll".
>   Method 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper..ctor' not found.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because custom msbuild code or NuGet packages you use are using a pre-MSBuild 15 way of referencing MSBuild's `CodeTaskFactory`.

Check all of your project / build files for occurrences of `UsingTask` elements referencing `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll` or `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll` (or similar dll reference) and change the dll to `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll`.

If the problematic code comes from a NuGet package, see if an update to the package is available or contact its authors.